# Упорядочить массив, содержащий координаты точек, чтобы создать замкнутый полигон

Tags: python

Есть набор координат в случайном порядке. Требуется упорядочить точки так, что бы получился замкнутый контур без пересечений рёбер.

Вероятно однозначного ответа может не быть, тогда предполагаю выбирать контур с минимальным периметром.

Т.е. имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пробовал использовать готовые пакеты для нахождения Concave Hull/Alpha Shape, но при этом пропускаются некоторые точки.

Кроме того пробовал алгоритм из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164896/8058496) на подобный вопрос. Но при большом количестве точек полный перебор всех возможных перестановок выходит очень долгим.

Буду рад любым советам. Куда смотреть, что почитать.

1. Пакет alphashape

```
    import alphashape

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    points = [
        [30.2327664, 59.9457466], [30.2342787, 59.9456499], [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2326936, 59.9457579],
        [30.2370232, 59.9447672], [30.2357721, 59.9442218], [30.2357188, 59.9442059], [30.2310267, 59.9459625],
        [30.2352922, 59.9441033], [30.2342418, 59.9451794], [30.2356708, 59.9459594], [30.2325756, 59.9454373],
        [30.2317671, 59.9430963], [30.2354012, 59.9461423], [30.2320000, 59.9432289], [30.2321622, 59.9432709],
        [30.2345152, 59.9455305], [30.2335813, 59.9436467], [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2345618, 59.9456060],
        [30.2367058, 59.9444656], [30.2370621, 59.9448292], [30.2344635, 59.9455385], [30.2314986, 59.9435107],
        [30.2321512, 59.9432815], [30.2309007, 59.9454682], [30.2320584, 59.9431722], [30.2310421, 59.9446529],
        [30.2327082, 59.9457816], [30.2310559, 59.9460404], [30.2347403, 59.9464515], [30.2368819, 59.9445064]
    ]

    hull = alphashape.alphashape(points, 900)
    hull_pts = hull.exterior.coords.xy

    X = hull_pts[0]
    Y = hull_pts[1]
    XY = list(zip(hull_pts[0], hull_pts[1]))

    plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o')
    ax = plt.gca()
    for i, point in enumerate(XY):
        ax.annotate(i, point)
    plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Пакет geopolygon

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from geopolygon import ConcaveHull


points = [
    [30.2327664, 59.9457466], [30.2342787, 59.9456499], [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2326936, 59.9457579],
    [30.2370232, 59.9447672], [30.2357721, 59.9442218], [30.2357188, 59.9442059], [30.2310267, 59.9459625],
    [30.2352922, 59.9441033], [30.2342418, 59.9451794], [30.2356708, 59.9459594], [30.2325756, 59.9454373],
    [30.2317671, 59.9430963], [30.2354012, 59.9461423], [30.2320000, 59.9432289], [30.2321622, 59.9432709],
    [30.2345152, 59.9455305], [30.2335813, 59.9436467], [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2345618, 59.9456060],
    [30.2367058, 59.9444656], [30.2370621, 59.9448292], [30.2344635, 59.9455385], [30.2314986, 59.9435107],
    [30.2321512, 59.9432815], [30.2309007, 59.9454682], [30.2320584, 59.9431722], [30.2310421, 59.9446529],
    [30.2327082, 59.9457816], [30.2310559, 59.9460404], [30.2347403, 59.9464515], [30.2368819, 59.9445064]
]

hull_poly = ConcaveHull.concaveHull(np.array(points), 3)
hull_poly_arr = np.array(hull_poly)

X = [x for x, _ in hull_poly_arr]
Y = [y for _, y in hull_poly_arr]

plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o')
ax = plt.gca()
for i, point in enumerate(hull_poly_arr):
    ax.annotate(i, point)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создай выпуклый полигон, потом добавь впуклости вставками

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263284/create-non-intersecting-polygon-passing-through-all-given-points) есть варианты

Comment: @eri , можете на пальцах объяснить как "добавить впуклости вставками"?

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание, что точка `30.2308853, 59.9450448` повторяется в вашем списке с координатами два раза. На графике она также имеет два номера - `0` и `31`, которые наложились друг на друга. Таким образом, в списке `points` 31 уникальная точка, при 32 элементах. Понятно, что это сделано для замыкания полигона при отрисовке.

#### Вариант №1

По алгоритму из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623817/2913477) (на английском).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = [
            [30.2327664, 59.9457466], [30.2342787, 59.9456499],
            [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2326936, 59.9457579],
            [30.2370232, 59.9447672], [30.2357721, 59.9442218],
            [30.2357188, 59.9442059], [30.2310267, 59.9459625],
            [30.2352922, 59.9441033], [30.2342418, 59.9451794],
            [30.2356708, 59.9459594], [30.2325756, 59.9454373],
            [30.2317671, 59.9430963], [30.2354012, 59.9461423],
            [30.2320000, 59.9432289], [30.2321622, 59.9432709],
            [30.2345152, 59.9455305], [30.2335813, 59.9436467],
            [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2345618, 59.9456060],
            [30.2367058, 59.9444656], [30.2370621, 59.9448292],
            [30.2344635, 59.9455385], [30.2314986, 59.9435107],
            [30.2321512, 59.9432815], [30.2309007, 59.9454682],
            [30.2320584, 59.9431722], [30.2310421, 59.9446529],
            [30.2327082, 59.9457816], [30.2310559, 59.9460404],
            [30.2347403, 59.9464515], [30.2368819, 59.9445064]
        ]

leftmost_point, *_, rightmost_point = sorted(points, key=lambda lst: lst[0])
x1, y1 = leftmost_point
x2, y2 = rightmost_point

border_slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

points_below_border = [(x1, y1)]
points_above_border = [(x2, y2)]

for x, y in points:
    border = border_slope * (x - x1) + y1
    if y < border:
        points_below_border.append((x, y))
    elif y > border:
        points_above_border.append((x, y))

points_below_border.sort()
points_above_border.sort(reverse=True)

points_above_border.append((x1, y1))

merged_points = points_below_border + points_above_border

x_lst = [x for x, _ in merged_points]
y_lst = [y for _, y in merged_points]

plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst, marker='o')

ax = plt.gca()
for number, point in enumerate(merged_points[:-1]):
    ax.annotate(number, point)

plt.show()
```

**Результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Вариант №2

Придумал свой способ, на примере из вопроса работает, на других не проверял.

**Идея:** найти точку равноудалённую от всех (центроид), вычислить наклон  и длину воображаемой линии, проведённой от центроида до каждой точки. Отсортировать исходные координаты на основании этих значений.

[image: Линии от центроида ко всем точкам]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import asin, degrees, sqrt

def order(centroid_x, centroid_y, points):
    lst = []
    for x, y in points:
        adjacent = x - centroid_x 
        opposite = y - centroid_y 
        hypotenuse = sqrt(adjacent**2 + opposite**2)
        sine = abs(opposite) / hypotenuse
        angle = degrees(asin(sine))

        if adjacent < 0 and opposite > 0:
            angle = 180 - angle
        elif adjacent < 0 and opposite < 0:
            angle += 180
        elif adjacent > 0 and opposite < 0:
            angle = 360 - angle

        lst.append((angle, hypotenuse, x, y))

    # Сортируем по углу и расстоянию от центра до точки
    lst.sort(key=lambda tup: (tup[0], tup[1]))
    # Замыкаем фигуру, чтобы была линия от последней точки к первой
    lst.append(lst[0])

    return [(x, y) for _, _, x, y in lst]

points = [
            [30.2327664, 59.9457466], [30.2342787, 59.9456499],
            [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2326936, 59.9457579],
            [30.2370232, 59.9447672], [30.2357721, 59.9442218],
            [30.2357188, 59.9442059], [30.2310267, 59.9459625],
            [30.2352922, 59.9441033], [30.2342418, 59.9451794],
            [30.2356708, 59.9459594], [30.2325756, 59.9454373],
            [30.2317671, 59.9430963], [30.2354012, 59.9461423],
            [30.2320000, 59.9432289], [30.2321622, 59.9432709],
            [30.2345152, 59.9455305], [30.2335813, 59.9436467],
            [30.2308853, 59.9450448], [30.2345618, 59.9456060],
            [30.2367058, 59.9444656], [30.2370621, 59.9448292],
            [30.2344635, 59.9455385], [30.2314986, 59.9435107],
            [30.2321512, 59.9432815], [30.2309007, 59.9454682],
            [30.2320584, 59.9431722], [30.2310421, 59.9446529],
            [30.2327082, 59.9457816], [30.2310559, 59.9460404],
            [30.2347403, 59.9464515], [30.2368819, 59.9445064]
        ]

centroid_x = sum(x for x, _ in points) / len(points)
centroid_y = sum(y for _, y in points) / len(points)

ordered_points = order(centroid_x, centroid_y, points)

x_lst = [x for x, _ in ordered_points]
y_lst = [y for _, y in ordered_points]

plt.plot(x_lst, y_lst, marker='o')

ax = plt.gca()
for number, point in enumerate(ordered_points[:-1]):
    ax.annotate(number, point)

plt.scatter(centroid_x, centroid_y, color="red")
plt.show()
```

**Результат**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: 1. Если  центроид и две (или больше) точек исходного массива лежат на одной прямой, причем все точки - по одну сторону от центроида -  работать не будет. Надо ставить дополнительную проверку.  2. Переход к полярным координатам с центроидом в центре по идее должно существенно упростить алгоритм. Просто - сортировка по полярному углу. А в остальном - вполне разумная идея.

Comment: Ответ, который должен получиться, показан на втором графике в вопросе.

Comment: @Duncan Добавил ещё один вариант. Сейчас больше похоже на требуемый график, но есть небольшие различия.

Comment: @MiniMax этот вариант тоже пробовал. Сейчас пробую вариант с триангуляцией Делоне. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266101/8058496

Comment: @Duncan 1) Когда получится, создайте ответ со своим решением. 2) Почему нужно получить в точности полигон со второго графика? Это полигон с минимальным периметром? 3) Как этот образец был получен, вручную?

Comment: @MiniMax 1) Если получится, то обязательно выложу. 2,3)Это тестовое задание. Надо получить контур реального земельного участка. Возможно даже с не минимальным периметром. Про минимальный периметр - это было моё предположение.

Answer (score 0):

Бери 4 точки: минимум-максимум по x и y. получается [A,B,C,D]

Потом бери точку из оставшихся и считай растояние до отрезков из того массива (AB,BC,CD,DA)

Вставляешь точку E между координатами до которых ближе [ABECD]

Следующую точку до отрезков (AB,BE,EC,CD,DA)